# Is it good practice to use this NSManagedObjectContext throughout the all app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

My app uses Core Data, I used the CoreData template when created my project in Xcode, so I already got `NSManagedObjectContext` object in my AppDelegate file, but Is it good practice to use this context throughout the all app (move it from one viewController to another)?
or maybe it's better to allocate more for different reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most apps I have done I have generally only created a new managedObjectContext if I am going to do work in a background thread.

I tend pass the managedObjectContext from a presenting viewController to the presented viewController by assigning an ivar or if the controller simply won't work without some CoreData magic I put it in the designated init method.

If I am selecting a row in a table and presenting a new viewController I will just pass along the managedObject that was selected and then if I need the managedObjectContext I can just use `[managedObject managedObjectContext];`

I don't like the idea of the singleton as Core Data stuff is already hard enough to isolate for testing without classes breaking the tell don't ask rule.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine doing that. What you have to observe, is that, if you want to manage multiple database entrys with multithread, you have to use locking in your object context, and create multiple object contexts to achieve a higher safety, ensuring that more than one context doesn't write on the same database at the same time and also avoiding multiple calls to the same context which would cause dead lock in your database.

Comment: take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385 for more information about concurrentcy & coreData

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely ok to do so (at least if you stay in the GUI-Thread). But you were asking about good practice. That's where the Core Data template of Xcode could be improved. Read this [Blogentry](http://nachbaur.com/blog/smarter-core-data) to learn how Apple should have done it better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are good to go with that only. Copy that `NSManagedObjectContext` from `AppDelegate` file whenever you need it in any class.. Use this line to copy it. I use it in my project and works cool:

```
 if (self.managedObjectContext == nil) 
{ 
    self.managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
    NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@", self.managedObjectContext);
}
```